# When sperm and egg mix, are the genes rearranged?

Tags: human-genetics

I remember once my high school teacher said when the sperm fertilizes the egg the genes are mixed very randomly, is that true?

Comment: It is rather wrong! Segregation and recombination both occur at the moment of the formation of the gametes (meiosis) and not at the moment of the fertilization. You might want to have a look at the wiki articles for meiosis, recombination and segregation.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Perhaps you should clarify with your teacher about what exactly they wanted to say. Or otherwise you should clarify what you really mean by "mixing"? Sure, because of diffusion, the paternal and maternal chromosomes would be uniformly distributed in the nuclear space.

Answer (score 1):

No.  When sperm and ova are forming, the chromosomes you inherited from your mother lines up with the chromosome you inherited from your father, and "crossing over" happens.  It would be like taking a Merriam-Webster dictionary, and another brand of dictionary, and picking a random point (like say, the middles of the "C" section), cutting both books at that point, and joining the portion of one with the portion of the other, making new books that are part Merriam Webster, and part the other kind of dictionary.  That happens in every chromosome, and the gamete is made up of those franken-chromosomes.